# Dúvida no tratamento de retorno Ajax, receber retorno de dados de uma API

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Tenho uma API asp.net web.api

Estou fazendo um método que envia as informações de login, estou com dificuldade para fazer o tratamento do retorno, mesmo enviando informações erradas está passando como certas.

```
<script>
        var usuario, senha;


        $(function(){
            //login
            $("#envia").click(function(){
                usuario = $("#txt-email").val();
                senha = $("#txt-password").val();

               if (usuario != "" && senha != ""){
                    $.ajax({type:"POST",
                            url:"http://appcasino.rocasafari.com.br/api/usuario/consulta/"+usuario+"/"+senha,
                            //url:"http://localhost:59791/api/usuario/consulta/",
                            //data:({usuario, senha}),
                            cache: false,
                            datatype: "json",
                            crossDomain: true,
                            beforeSend: function(){ $("#mensagem").text('Espere, por favor...');},
                            success: continua,
                            error: noConexion
                    });
               } 

            });

        });
        /**********************************************/

        function continua(dados){
            console.info(dados);
            if(dados=="[]"){
                document.getElementById("#txt-email").value = "";
                document.getElementById("#txt-password").value = "";
                alert("O usuário ou sua senha está errado");
                return;
            }
            alert("Bem vindo: "+dados);
            $.mobile.changePage($("#perguntas"),"none");
        }
        /*****************************************/
        function noConexion(){
            alert("Não tem uma conexão  ");
        }
 </script>
```

Comment: Uma observação, `success` e `error` foram substituídos por `done` e `fail`, passar o usuário e senha pela url não é muito recomendado, e no seu `data` que está comentado tem um erro de sintaxe: `{ usuario: 'meuusuario', senha: 'minhasenha' }`, se você está usando o JQuery apenas por causa do AJAX recomendo que não faça isso, use a API do `fetch` ou faça o XHR na mão

Comment: Agradeço, mais a sua resposta não me ajudou, porque no momento minha dúvida e fazer o tratamento do retorno da consulta

Comment: era apenas uma observação

Comment: Em algum momento essa sua checkagem, `if(dados=="[]")`,  é válida?  Pois você só vai mostrar a mensagem de usuário e senha incorreta se a condição entrar nesse loop, se você espera receber um array com informações em `dados` me parece que você deveria verificar `if(dados.length <= 0)`